# Subsite Search goes to default search page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

My SharePoint subsite search always go to default page(_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx).I have configured custom search result page in search settings.But no luck.However on the root site its going to my configured search result page.

Comment: What happens when you switch to "Everything" before you make the search?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the custom search page for the subsite. If it's not set, it will by default go to the `(_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx)` page.

To set the custom page, follow the below steps:

1) Ensure you have admin privileges.

2) Go to the Site Settings page > Click on Search Settings as below:

[image]

3) On the Search settings page, (https://sitecollection/subsite/_layouts/15/enhancedSearch.aspx?level=site), you can set the custom search page. Set you page url, click OK

[image]

4) After setting the page url, all the queries would be redirected to this page.